# How can I show the ready path given with Jetstream?

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect to a different page from the register screen.
config/fortify.php

```
'home' => function(){
      return route('front.loginHomePage');
    },
```

When I change from here, the redirection of the login also changes.
I just want to change the register. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because when you registered, also you are logged in